# Is there any way to display the Out of Range, Remembered WIFI network in to our android application

Tags: android, android-wifi

I wanted to display all the networks which are available in my android mobile WIFI settings, even though they are in out of range. and I am unable to get them(Not inRange, Remembered Network) with ScanResult. Is there any alternative way to Display Not in Range Remembered Network to display into my application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `getScanResults()`, that's going to display only the currently in range networks. Use [`WifiManager#getConfiguredNetworks()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks%28%29) to return a `List<WifiConfiguration>` of the remembered networks.